# Should SO Jobs advertisement have appropriate comment format?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

Shouldn't "A career site that's by developers, for developers." be in a comment block, or on multiple single-line comments? The `C++`-style or `C`-style comments should suffice:

```
// A career site that's by
// developers, for developers.
```

Or:

```
/* A career site that's by
   developers, for developers. */
```

I mean, we *are* programmers, after all.

[image: Current image]

Comment: _A career site that's by developers_ -- so, who built all those other career sites?  (Also, I remember reading that Careers was renamed Jobs because, after honest reflection, it wasn't helping people find careers, merely their next job.  It's funny to see it described as a _career site_ again.)

Comment: Putting it in comment blocks would make it harder to read, as I assume the text becomes a nice gray as comments should. I honestly don't mind.

Comment: @ThomasYates The color can be changed, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom There is a **lot** more to building a website than the actual development. Who built all those other career sites? Product people, whose job isn't writing code, *not* developers.

Comment: Strange this question is at +72 but a similar question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339350/73226 was heavily downvoted and deleted by 3 20K+ users.

Comment: @MartinSmith I was completely unaware of that question. (I don't have the reputation on [Meta.SE] to see it.)

Comment: @EBrown - I wasn't expecting that you would have seen it. It was despatched quite quickly. Here's what it looked like for posterity  https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBRCD.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to have been updated.

[image: New SO Jobs advertisement]

Answer (score -7):

As [@Jeffrey Bosboom](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339789/should-so-jobs-advertisement-have-appropriate-comment-format#comment422602_339789) wrote:

> A career site that's by developers -- so, who built all those other career sites? (Also, I remember reading that Careers was renamed Jobs because, after honest reflection, it wasn't helping people find careers, merely their next job. It's funny to see it described as a career site again.)

Coming to the question, putting them in the comments makes the color font really grey to the extent that most people would ignore it.

Perhaps, if you would change the color font it would make a difference and putting it in a multi-comment format is much cleaner.

Comment: We don't *necessarily* have to change the font colour - just add the comment tokens around it to make it *look* real. :)

Comment: I found your suggesting to use multiline comments `/* multi line */` and better coloring  really good - so +1 from me.
I wonder why you received all the downvotes - was it the quote about next job versus career?